# Can I scale layout to a smaller screen?

Tags: javascript, css, layout, pixel-ratio

I did layout (using flex) for width 1280px. But it turned out that screen on which it will be shown has only 960px of browser width (and 1280px os screen width with some fractional pixel ratio)

Do I have any simple option programmatically to scale my layout to new size, something like "zoom out" it?

Comment: By default, the layout is not adapting to the width of the screen ? Do you have a code example ?

Comment: it was done one design for screens <1280, and another for >=1280, but now I should change threshold to 960
http://zmanim.lasil.ru:8080/?city_name=Челябинск&template=chelyabinsk

Answer (score -1):

you can use

```css
html {
  font-size: 80%;
}
```

this will decrease your all html elements sizing. :)

Comment: This will only decrease the font size, not the width of his flex layout.

Comment: html {
  transform: scale(0.75); 
  transform-origin: 0 0; 
}


it'll work try it

Comment: that's not what your answer suggests

Comment: for e.g.

 

.container {
  transform: scale(0.75); /* Adjust the scale value as needed */
  transform-origin: 0 0; /* Ensures scaling from the top-left corner */
}